# Badly-formatted WSUS 2016 update reports

Tags: wsus, windows-server-2016, report

I've installed WSUS on Windows Server 2016 to replace an old WSUS 3.0 server, and the detailed updates reports are badly formatted, with a lot of the information apparently truncated. These reports are split into five; Description, Approval Summary, Status Summary, Computer Detailed Status Report and Report Options.

On our old WSUS 3.0 server, these sections are displayed, with a vertical scrollbar, with the Description, Approval Summary and Status Summary following on from each other, with Computer Detailed Status Report on a separate set of pages and finally Report Options on its own page at the end. All parts are readable.

On the new server, these four sections are displayed with no vertical scrollbar, with the first page split vertically into two parts. The top part shows the Description and possibly the Approval Summary (which is hidden), the bottom part shows the Status Summary. On the next page, the Computer Detailed Status Report is shown (truncated), followed by a blank page, then the Report Options. 
We've reinstalled WSUS several times, and played about with the report layout and choices, and nothing seems to correct the problem.

[Sample WSUS 2016 report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtjOO.png) (Apologies for the format of the image--with pages going left-to-right, top-to-bottom--but I can't post more than 2 links as a site newbie.)

Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was the version of "Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime" (v11.0.2100.60) that was installed on the server. I resolved the issue by downloading a newer version (v11.1.3452.0) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35747 and updating it on the server.

For the record, the version of "Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012" I had installed on that server was the v11.0.2100.60 of the x64 package, downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29065#SQLSYSCLR.